# SAT to k-in-3-SAT reduction

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat

Given a 3-SAT clause. Is there a way to convert 3-SAT to k-in-3-SAT such that:

The number of new variables introduced are less than the number of clauses (without adding dummy clauses etc.)?

The standard way is by introducing 4 new variables and 3 new clauses as mentioned here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

If not is it possible for some N-SAT (N>3)?

Comment: What is k? It stands for 1 or 2? If so, maybe you should just write 1 instead of k.

Comment: @domotorp k can be any fixed constant which we are free to choose as long as the main requirement is satisfied

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to convert 2SAT to X3SAT that adds only one new variable per clause.

$(a \lor b) \rightarrow (\bar a, \bar b, x)$

where $x$ is a new variable unique to this clause.

I don't know of any shorter methods for converting 3SAT other than the normal method.